# Layout Height AppCompat Not Full Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

What's wrong with AppCompat?
My application does not use AppCompat and there are no problems with XML Layout
But after I use AppCompat why is the XML Layout not full on the screen?

[image]

I tried by creating a new XML layout, but the results were the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: i think its issue with your app theme can you share the theme of that activity

Comment: @NileshRathod Yes you are right, this problem has been resolved after adding the theme. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this theme to your `activity`

in `style.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and define this style to your activity in `AndroidManifest` :

```
<activity
android:name=".YourActivity"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

Using this will remove the extra space coming for `toolbar` by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve fullscreen mode when you use `AppCompact` like this

Add this to your style file

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
  parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And in your manifest file add this to your `Activity` tag

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
```