# Why a programatically absolute view position is not absolute?

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, dynamic

My source code is in *Kotlin* (fully interoperable with *Java*) with *Android Studio 3.4.1*.

I have a serious error problem in absolute positioning of dynamic created views. My relative layout is empty, with no view. I've read all *Stack Overflow* question related to this, but there is no help for me.

I've reduced my code to a minimum, just for show my pain for the community:

My *activity* code is

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val mt = this.resources.displayMetrics
        wScreen = mt.widthPixels    // 1080 pixels 
        hScreen = mt.heightPixels   // 1920 pixels
        bt =  Button(this)
        myLayout.addView(bt) // MyLayoit is relative layout ID
        bt.id = View.generateViewId()
        bt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)

         // % view height is 6,3% of screen heigth  
        bt.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams   
              (round(0.1786* wScreen).toInt(),   //193 pixels
               round(0.0633*hScreen).toInt())    // 122 pixels

       // top button is 92,7% of height screen
         bt.x = 0.0179F * wScreen //  Left position: 19 pixels
        bt.y = 0.927F * hScreen   //  Top position: 1780 pixels
    }  // On Create
}  // Main Activity
```

My relative layout XML is empty:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=
          "br.com.greatsolutions.paulo.yourcalcs.MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

The emulator has dimensions 2392x1440 shows 30% height cut more
a small margin below the button. I know that because I put the same button in different position.

[image: Nexus 6 API 25]

My cell phone dimension is 1920x1080. It shows the same screen

It will be very nice if someone could help me. I need a precise dynamic positioning in my app...

**Update 1:** I try to run using *Frame Layout* instead *Relative Layout*. No success.

**Update 2:** I've discovered a solution. It's different that I've expected, but it works. Persistence is the mother of invention. I did not have noticed the small green top bar...

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the solution for my misery. It is something almost crazy 
and very little addressed on the *Internet*. There is nothing to to with my program. It's not related if is coded in *Java* or *Kotlin*.

My project had a style in `styles.xml` (`app/res/values` in *Android project structure*) to rid of status bar with program title at top:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And in `AndroidManifest.xml` (`app/Manifest` in *Android project structure*) I've replate the previous theme setting  for below line, under `application` tag

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

When I was reprogramming my project in *Java* (maybe to submit to the community) and run, I've noticed that the program title has appearead again at top and therefore my button disappears below.

Ok, no problem. I was back in *Kotlin* project and made that above changes in my new *Java* project.

So the button appears, but it appeared cutted, in the same way of my original project in *Kotlin*.

However, I guessed: It will be that my cutting problem is related with this stuff?

I search again for how to take out title bar in apps and I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610855/layout-height-appcompat-not-full-screen) in *Stack Overflow*.

The post shows 2 news lines that I  never saw before. Maybe...
So I've added in `NoActionBar` styles 2 additional lines.

```
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

In fact, this `windowFullScreen` flag solves my original question totally!!! 
What changes have there been? The small green top bar status with battery level, phone signal and other stuff disappears from my screen. This is the effect of full screen setting

[image: Now it's ok!]